# Delete item in array from item?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`req.user.hails[0]` is an instance of the class hails, it has the method `cancel()`
I call it like this:

```
req.user.hails[0].cancel()
```

Can I from inside that instance remove the item itself?

```
    cancel: function() {
        //this will remove the item from a databae
        this.destroy()
        //Here I want to delete "this".
    }
```

The desired result is that `req.user.hails.length` is one shorter than before. I know I can remove it from where I'm calling cancel.

Comment: No, you have to remove it from the list. The code in `cancel()` can do that if it knows what array it's part of, but that would be a pretty fragile design in most cases. Objects don't "know" where references to themselves might be found, in general.

Comment: Ideally `cancel` should set some status or flag and then you should used all elements which do not have this flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't, not unless it happens (which is unlikely) that `cancel` closes over `req`, `req.user`, or `req.user.hails`. (And even then, it would be a **really** dodgy thing to do.) If it doesn't there's no information provided to your method that you can use to remove the entry from the array.

You could add a method to `hails` that both does the cancellation *and* removes the entry:

```
req.user.hails.cancelEntry = function(index) {
    this[index].cancel();
    this.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Yes, you can really add non-index properties to arrays like that. Note that they'll be enumerable, which is one reason not to use `for-in` loops to loop through arrays. (More about looping arrays in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) and its answers.)

You could make it non-enumerable:

```
Object.defineProperty(req.user.hails, "cancelEntry", {
    value: function(index) {
        this[index].cancel();
        this.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

In ES2015+, you could even create a subclass of `Array` that had `cancelEntry` on its prototype...